# Canvacord is not a constructor

Tags: canvas, discord.js

I just installed Canvacord and when starting my discord bot I got an error message in the terminal, here it is:

**TypeError: Canvacord is not a constructor**

```
 const Canvacord = require ("canvacord");
 const canvas = new Canvacord ();

 const {author} = require ("canvacord");
```

Answer (score 0):

`Canvacord` itself cannot be instantiated with `new`. Instead, you have to use the class provided within `Canvacord`, of which ([according to their documentation](https://canvacord.js.org/#/docs/main/v5/general/welcome)) there are 5 ([Leaver](https://canvacord.js.org/#/docs/main/v5/class/Leaver), [Rank](https://canvacord.js.org/#/docs/main/v5/class/Rank), [Spotify](https://canvacord.js.org/#/docs/main/v5/class/Spotify), [Util](https://canvacord.js.org/#/docs/main/v5/class/Util), and [Welcomer](https://canvacord.js.org/#/docs/main/v5/class/Welcomer)).

All of those, you can instantiate depending on your usage. For example, to instantiate `Util`, use:

```js
var util = new Canvacord.Util();
```

You can read more about how to use each available class in their documentation. They've also provided examples for some of those classes that you can use as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

For all memes/image-gen, you have to use `Canvacord.Canvas`:

```js
const Canvacord = require("canvacord");

Canvacord.Canvas.trigger("./image.png")
  .then(buffer => {
    Canvacord.write(buffer, "./triggered.gif");
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```